# How to catch which columns are throwing warnings in sapply?

Tags: r, sapply

I have a df, which should be all numerics, but which are all typed as characters. I am trying this:

```
sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

Which throws warnings:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I can ignore the warnings, but I would like to find where the issues are. How do I find which column(s) is/are throwing warnings?

This seems fairly basic, but I cannot figure out how to get it.

If it helps:

```
test <- as.data.frame(list(c("1","2","3"), c("1","poop","3")))
> sapply(test, as.numeric)
     c..1....2....3.. c..1....poop....3..
[1,]                1                   1
[2,]                2                  NA
[3,]                3                   3
Warning message:
In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What I would like is a function which tells me that column 2 is the problematic one.

Comment: What does warnings()[1:5] show? (Probably will be saying that some factor variables were coerced to NA.) Would be safer to use `function(x){ as.numeric(as.character(x))}`

Comment: There might be a better way to do this, but you can print out the row and turn warnings into errors with `options(warn=2)` so it breaks when it encounters one.

Comment: For future reference please include a reproducible example (including data)

Comment: ? It is a simple dataframe of characters. It is arbitrary and relatively simple to reproduce a data frame of characters. I just need to know if there is a way to see which throw the error.

Comment: `sapply(test, function(x) tryCatch(as.numeric(x), warning = function(w) "This one!!!"))`

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this, but apparently I screwed something up. Thanks for knocking my screws back into place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RichScriven.

This works:

```
test2 <- sapply(test, function(x) tryCatch(as.numeric(x), warning = function(w) "This one!!!"))
which(test2 == "This one!!!")
```